# ERROR: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.storage.StorageStatus after upgrading spark-snowflake connector

Tags: java, apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

After upgrading the spark snowflake connector jar I am using running my application on AWS EMR 6.6.0 to spark-snowflake_2.12:2.11.0-spark_3.2
I get the following error

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.storage.StorageStatus
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.storage.StorageStatus, value: org.apache.spark.storage.StorageStatus@6ea056eb)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Lorg.apache.spark.storage.StorageStatus;, size 17)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.serialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RemoteNettyRpcCallContext.send(NettyRpcCallContext.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcCallContext.reply(NettyRpcCallContext.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$anonfun$receiveAndReply$1.applyOrElse(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.$anonfun$process$1(Inbox.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$MessageLoop$$receiveLoop(MessageLoop.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop$$anon$1.run(MessageLoop.scala:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Although my application still completes, I am not sure why this error is occurring, but it dramatically slows down my application.

Comment: There's no Snowflake Spark connector function call in the stacktrace which makes me think it's not related to Snowflake. Have you enabled logging and does the log show anything extra?

Comment: @user19627118 Did you find the reason for the error?